# Sitecore HOWTO: Search item bucket for items with specific values

Tags: search, sitecore, sitecore7, bucket, sitecore7.5

I have an item bucket with more then 30 000 items inside. What I need is to quickly search items that have particular field set to particular value, or even better is to make something like SELECT WHERE fieldValue IN (1,2,3,4) statement. Are there any ready solutions?
I searched the web and the only thing I found is "Developer's Guide to Item
Buckets and Search" but there is no code examples.

Comment: As you can see you can by answer below you can use the sitecore 7 api. The quick start guides links were written by me be so I'd appreciate if took that into account when marking the answer.  Hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Using Sitecore Content Editor**:

Go to the bucket item then In search tab, start typing the following (replace fieldname and value with actual field name and value):

> custom:fieldname|value

Then hit enter, you see the result of the query, you can multiple queries at once if you want.

**Using Sitecore Content Search API:**

```cs
using Sitecore.ContentSearch;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Utilities

ID bucketItemID = "GUID of your bucket item";
ID templateID = "Guid of your item's template under bucket";
string values = "1,2,3,4,5";

using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index").CreateSearchContext())
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
    predicate = PredicateBuilder.And(item => item.TemplateId == new ID(templateID) 
                                     && item.Paths.Contains(bucketItemID));
    var innerPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<SearchResultItem>();
    foreach(string val in values.Split(','))
    {
         innerPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<SearchResultItem>();
         innerPredicate = innerPredicate.Or(item => item["FIELDNAME"] == val);
    }
    predicate = predicate.And(innerPredicate);

    var result = predicate.GetResults();
    List<Item> ResultsItems = new List<Item>();
    foreach (var hit in result.Hits)
    {
       Item item = hit.Document.GetItem();
       if(item !=null)
       {
          ResultsItems .Add(item);
       }
    }
}
```

The following links can give good start with the Search API:

1. http://www.fusionworkshop.co.uk/news-and-insight/tech-lab/sitecore-7-search-a-quickstart-guide#.VPw8AC4kWnI
2. https://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/sitecore-7-development-team/posts/2013/06/sitecore-7-poco-explained.aspx
3. https://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/sitecore-7-development-team/posts/2013/05/sitecore-7-predicate-builder.aspx

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

You need something like this. The Bucket item is an IIndexable so it can be searched using Sitecore 7 search API.

This code snippet below can easily be adapted to meet your needs and it's just a question of modifying the where clause.if you need any further help with the sitecore 7 syntax just write a comment on the QuickStart blog post below and I'll get back to you.

```
var bucketItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(bucketPath);
  if (bucketItem != null && BucketManager.IsBucket(bucketItem))
  {     
     using (var searchContext = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(bucketItem as IIndexable).CreateSearchContext())
    {
        var result = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem().Where(x => x.Name == itemName).FirstOrDefault();
        if(result != null)
            Context.Item = result.GetItem();
    }
  }
```

Further reading on my blog post here:

http://coreblimey.azurewebsites.net/sitecore-7-search-quick-start-guide/

Comment: Do you know why bucketItem as IIndexable would be null?

Comment: @Ernesto I'm really late to the party here but the fix should be passing your item to the SitecoreIndexableItem value constructor. `var indexableItem = new SitecoreIndexableItem(bucketItem);`